# Работа с сессиями php

Tags: php, сессия

Есть список товаров в корхине. У каждого товара есть счётчик количества. Каким образом можно заставить запомнить этот счётчик через сессии, чтобы при обновлении не сбрасывались?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При увеличении/уменьшении количества товаров в корзине, выполняете соответствующее действие в вашей переменной $_SESSION, где вы будете хранить артикулы товаров и их количество.
К примеру

```
$_SESSION['cart']['13412']['1'];
$_SESSION['cart']['13116']['3'];
```

Comment: А каким образом осуществлять запись для нужного элемента. Сам обработчик что из себя будет представлять? Через JS?

Comment: @oskar ну я же не знаю логику вашего приложения. как угодно можно обрабатывать, ну разумнее конечно да, через JS это осуществлять, на сервер ajax запрос отправлять, чтобы менять количество соответственно.